# Version conflict between gms:play-services-vision and firebase

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-firebase

I've installed both react-native-firebase and react-native-camera. The camera was fine when play-services -vision was stuck at `12.0.1`, but I just ran into this error (**Error updating property googleVisionBarcodeDetectorEnable**)  https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1844 that requires an upgrade to `15.0.2`.

It looks like there are Google Play Services and Firebase conflicts when `play-services-vision` is bumped up to `15.0.2` from `12.0.1`:

```
Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
  15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.3.4
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@16.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.6
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@15.0.2
```

I've tried `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@16.2.0` but it gave me `exceed 64k methods` error. 
Bumping up to 17.0.2 would cause a version conflict from `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement`.

Anyone using both react-native-firebase and react-native camera? Can you tell me how to solve this version conflict problem?

Here is the dependencies in android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
      exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
      implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
      implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
        force = true
      }
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-signin')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation(project(':react-native-google-signin')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'
}
```

Ext in android/build.gradle

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
}
```

Package:

```
"react-native-camera": "^1.6.4",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.1.1",
```

Comment: try this on app build.gradle com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

Comment: *exceed 64k methods*   you can enable multidex to remove the error

Answer (score 12):

You need to update the version of gms:play-services-vision.
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'`

Comment: for reference: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_13_2018

Answer (score 2):

For anyone here after ejecting from Expo (v34) into a react-native project wanting to use firebase, and if you kept using `expo-barcode-scanner`, the problem lies in it because it's using an older version of `play-services-vision`.

You have multiple options:

- If a new Expo SDK is released, use it. I'm sure the vision library will be upgraded.
- Remove `expo-barcode-scanner` as a dependency and use another one.
- Pump the version of the vision library in `expo-barcode-scanner` lib in `node_modules\expo-barcode-scanner\android\build.gradle` (discouraged)

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue. We solved in another way using gradle constraints: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable MultiDex because:

> total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX
>   file to 65,536

and by enable multidex , compiler will put extra methods/funcs in another dex file.

so do these steps:

1- Add MultiDex to build.gradle(Module file):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

2 -Clen & Build the project

3- Add  multiDexEnabled =true  to the same  buil.gradle(Module), inside

```
      android {  
       .... 
         defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled true
     ...
      } 
     }
```

to enable MultiDex

4- Add Application Class to your project &Override Application Class that extend it from MultiDexApplication instead of Application, for example  :

```
 java:   public class MyMultiDexApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
Kotlin :  class MyMultiDexApplication : MultiDexApplication() { override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate() } }
```

5- Add your Application Class name to the AndroidManifest.xml  in Application Tag:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyMultiDexApplication "
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
```

6-Add dependencies that you need like :

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@16.2.0
```

to build.gradle

7 - Build again and done

Google reference for more info :
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Answer (score -1):

My easy fix to avoid this happening when importing modules is

1) npm install
2) run-android / run-ios 
3) i get the same message or sometimes no message
4) i go to node_modules/react-native-component-name and find the android/build.gradle file , i change the compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to my version (latest), and , replace all dependencies with a plus

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2 => com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:+` 
That way the module always uses the latest libraries available